# Doubt about observer in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, onestepcheckout

I have a lot of observers that work like that:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_checkoutopt_index_pagamento>
    <observers>
        <auto_invoice_order>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>IsabelaFlores_SGPico_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>acessarCheckoutPagamento</method>
        </auto_invoice_order>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_checkoutopt_index_pagamento>
```

Where checkoutopt_index_pagamento: page`s URL with _ instead of /, and all of it worked fine, until now.

The problem: I have to put an observer to a checkout page with URL "checkoutopt/index/revisao", but file path "onestepcheckout/onestep.phtml" and it isn't working.

I already try to use onestepcheckout_onestep, onestepcheckout_onestep_index, onestepcheckout_onestep_index_revisao, onestepcheckout_onestep_revisao, and a lot of others combinations.

How exactly could I define a observer to this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the core code, you will find that this kind of event is dispatched in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php::postDispatch()` with

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
     'controller_action_postdispatch_'.$this->getFullActionName(),
     array('controller_action'=>$this)
);
```

So, you have to find out what is the result of `$this->getFullActionName()`. 
This will be `routeName_controllerName_actionName`.
For a fast debug, you could log it with some `Mage::log($this->getFullActionName())` in this method and access the url you want.